# Is $d(x, y)={(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|{x_i} -{y_i}|}^p})^{1/p}$ , $x, y\in\mathbb{R^n}$, $0<p<1$ metric on $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, holder-inequality, triangle-inequality

$X=\mathbb{R^n}$

Define ,
$d:X×X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by

$d(x, y)={(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{|{x_i} -{y_i}|}^p})^{1/p}$ , $x, y\in\mathbb{R^n}$, $0<p<1$

Question: Is $d$ a metric on $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Property : (1) Non-negativitiy
(2) Definiteness
(3) Symmetry
holds.

But, Since $0<p<1$ , hence we can't use Holder, Minkowski inequality. So, how can we prove triangle inequality?

Is there any inequality( like Minkowski that helps us to prove triangle inequality of $p-norm$ for $p\ge 1$) which helps us to prove triangle inequality for $0<p<1$.

Please give me hints to prove triangle inequality of $d$?
I can't able to proof triangle inequality.

Comment: The unit ball is not convex for $p < 1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Reverse_Inequality